# Using a Servlet variable in a JSP submit button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am looking for some suggestions and tips regarding Servlet/JSP issue I am trying to solve. I need to access a Servlet variable in JSP page which I am passing through the request.setAttribute, then the variable needs to be passed onto another Servlet through doPost. I am able pass that to the page and can display/print, but I would like it to be not displayed, but just passed on to the Submit button.

Here's my Servlet code:

```
request.setAttribute("jsession", jsession);
```

I can do the following and it works, but it's displaying it on the page and the end-user doesn't need to see this:

```
<select name="jsession">
    <c:forEach var="jsession" items="${jsession}">
        <option value="${jsession}">${jsession}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But, I am looking to do something like this:

```
String sess = ${jsession}.
```

This will be then passed onto the Submit button, maybe I am over-thinking this. Can some veterans point me in the right direction.  I  appreciate all the effort the veterans take in here. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need a hidden field instead of your select box:

```
<input type="hidden" name="jsession" value="<c:out value="${jsession}"/>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will give this a shot and respond. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello JB Nizet, This worked and exactly what I needed for now. But I wanted get general advice on something, do I have to start a new question for that or can I ask it here ?

Comment: If you think the question is a valid question for StackOverflow, then start a new question. Else, ask it here and I'll see if I can answer :-)

Comment: Hello @JB Nizet, Thanks for your response. I am looking for general suggestions/comments/best-practices in my approach. So I am doing the follwing here : 1) Connect to a URL and get JSESSION authentication token, and make further URL (REST calls) with the JSESSION ID to get XML response. I parse the XML response and display that on a JSP page and the JSP page calls another Servlet which eventually renders an image. I am using the above method you gave me by hiding the JSESSION string and keep passing it on to different JSPs.  Is my approach correct ? How can I improve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I don't have sufficient knowledge of what your appdoes and hos it's architected to answer.